# Adding list's elements after reading it from a file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What i am trying to do is read elements from a file and add each line to print its output now the problem is i have tried a number of ways but i am unsuccessful
for example if i want to access a certain number

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
         for s in line.split(' '):
             num = int(s)
             print(num[1])

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried another way to read each line store it in a list and then converting it into an int to use them later

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    filer = f.readlines()
    filer = map(int, filer)
    print(filer[1])
```

but it still gives me an error

```
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

I am a beginner at python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `map` returns a map object, which does not support indexing.

To get what you want, place that object in [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    filer = f.readlines()
    filer = list(map(int, filer))
    print(filer[1])
```

Or, you can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (which is often preferred):

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    filer = f.readlines()
    filer = [int(x) for x in filer]
    print(filer[1])
```

---

Also, I just wanted to add that `open` defaults to read-mode.  So, you can actually just do this:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
```

However, some people like to explicitly put the `'r'`, so I'll leave that choice to you.

Comment: when i tried to run the first code it gave me an error                        filer = list(map(int, filer))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0,2,3,2,7,5,3,4\n'

Comment: Huh.  Your file is structured far differently than I thought.  Judging by your code, I assumed there was 1 integer per line.

Comment: Ya it sort oF a 2D array

Comment: Well, if you want me to help you further, I'll be happy to.  However, I'll need a sample of the file and a sample of the output you want.  Otherwise, you can go with @wnnmaw's answer which you said solved your problem (although I don't see how).

Comment: well the code is his answer saves all the data in one column list , so i can access them separately , Thanks a lot for your answers they were really helpful . i am a beginner so i don't know much about python

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're saving your number as a single number, you want to use a list.  Try this

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    numList = []
    for line in f:
         for s in line.split(' '):
             numList.append(int(s))       
             print numList[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `print(num[1])` to `print(num)` if you want to just access one number at a time.